# Perform two task with jQuery and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, email

I have a form which a user fills in, the data is sent to my email, but I also wanted email to be posted to my mail chimp using api but it's not working at the moment.

Here is my form:

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return false;" id="dealerForm ">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
     <input id="subject" name="subject" value="Dealer partner message" type="hidden">
     <input class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" name="name" required="" type="text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" name="email" required="" type="email">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <input class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" name="phone" required="" type="tel">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
       <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Dearlership Info *" id="message" name="message" required=""></textarea>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
   <div class="col-lg-12 text-right">
      <button type="submit" class="btn send_msg">Send Message</button>
   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Here is my php with mail chimp api and mail send.

```
<?php

    // Email address verification
function isEmail($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

if($_POST) {

    $mailchimp_api_key = 'myapikey';  // enter your MailChimp API Key
    // ****
    $mailchimp_list_id = 'mylistID'; // enter your MailChimp List ID
    // ****

    $subscriber_email = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));

    if(!isEmail($subscriber_email)) {
        $array = array();
        $array['valid'] = 0;
        $array['message'] = 'Not a valid email address!';
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
    else {
        $array = array();
        $merge_vars = array();

        require_once 'mailchimp/php/MailChimp.php';

        $MailChimp = new \Drewm\MailChimp($mailchimp_api_key);
        $result = $MailChimp->call('lists/subscribe', array(
                'id'                => $mailchimp_list_id,
                'email'             => array('email' => $subscriber_email),
                'merge_vars'        => $merge_vars,
                'double_optin'      => false,
                'update_existing'   => true,
                'replace_interests' => false,
                'send_welcome'      => true,
        ));

        if($result == false) {
            $array['valid'] = 0;
            $array['message'] = 'An error occurred! Please try again later.';
        }
        else {
            $array['valid'] = 1;
            $array['message'] = 'Success! Please check your mail.';
        }

            echo json_encode($array);

     }

   }

        if (isset($_POST["email@mail.com"])) {
        $to      = 'mail@mail.com';
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $message = 'Name: '.$_POST["name"].'<br>Email: '.$_POST["email"].'<br>Phone: '.$_POST["phone"].'<br>Message: '.$_POST["message"];
            $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" .
            'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1;';

            if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            echo "New record created successfully";
        }
    }
?>
```

While my JQuery code:

```
$("#dealerForm").on("submit", function(){
    //debugger;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        var url;
        url: "contact/dealer.php",
        data: $("#dealerForm").serialize()
    }).done(function (data) {
        //debugger;
        console.log(data);
        window.location.href = "https://example.com/Thank%20You.html";
    });

    $("#dealerForm")[0].reset();
    return false;
});
```

Thanks for your comment and your help.

Comment: why don't you do both action in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Before mail-chimp fix I think you need to fix followings:

1. You don't need to use `onsubmit="return false;"` in form declaration. You already returned false in `jQuery onsubmit`. And also remove space from form ID name. So, your form declaration can be like `<form method="POST" id="dealerForm">`
2. Remove `var url;` from ajax

Now debug email/mailchimp code in dealer.php.

Comment: @Hussain Thank you for for you comment, I did what you suggested but it doesn't send a mail or submit user emails to the user.

Comment: The problem I marked which is the first problem. Now email doesn't send that is second problem. Email can not send for different reasons. Ensure there has no error in your PHP code. If you are testing in local environment ensure PHP mail configurations are correct that can send email and mailchimp api info's are correct as well

Comment: @Hussain if I separate php logic as   just the code to send email it sends with out a problem also the the mail chimp api, but when i combine both together doesn't work.

Comment: BTW, if (isset($_POST["email@mail.com"])) this is not correct. It should be if (isset($_POST["email"]))

Comment: That's my custom email which is supposed to send form data.

Comment: You can separate PHP logic but here the problem is different. Ok let me check with PHP code again.

Comment: I was still figuring out how I can make the php logic to 1. send the mail && 2. extract the email and post it to mail chimp. But I don't know how I can put that. I will appreciate. And am not sure if that should be done from php logic or query.

Comment: 1. I don't see any problem having both mailchimp and email code in the same file. But it would be better if you create 2 different class/files one for email and another for mailchimp and include those files in ajax url. Or you can create 2 different function one for mailchimp and another for email for code readability.
2. I tried with email code only and it works fine with me. Ensure $to is valid and (isset($_POST["email"])) used instead of if (isset($_POST["email@mail.com"])). Also ensure that you have mail configured